# Why is the adjective placed before a conjoined verb?

Tags: verb, adjective, sentence-structure, conjunction

I am using an app called Duolingo to practice learning German through assimilation techniques however I have come across something that is a bit confusing to me in a a way, regarding the way that words should be placed. In the following example you will see what I am talking about:

> **Translate Into German**
>
> The dog is strong although he is old.

I end up putting in:

> Der Hund ist stark, obwohl er ist alt.

However the actual translation that they are looking for is:

> Der Hund ist stark, obwohl er alt ist.

Would anyone know the proper rules for this so I can I figure out why this is and when? Thanks!

Comment: It is not about the adjective. The subordinate clausule that obwohl induces sends the verb to the last position.

Comment: Hmmm okay, I will have to look that up. I wasn't sure what it was called.

Comment: That's called [*Prädikativum*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prädikativum), or more precisely here *Prädikatsnomen* (predicative noun). It's the complement to the predicate. In "Er ist alt" 'Er' is the subject and 'ist alt' is the predicate. 'ist' again is called [*Kopula*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopula) (linking verb) and we already talked about 'alt' :) This is the [English Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar))

Comment: But.. Besides.. what is a "conjoined verb"?

Comment: I was thinking the way to describe the verb after a conjunction was 'conjoined'. I clearly do not remember the grammatical terms like I should lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Obwohl* is a subordinating conjunction. That means that in that clause it sends the verb(s) to the end. Some common subordinating conjunctions are *dass*, *damit*, *wenn*, *als*. And there are lots more.

> Ich will, dass du mitkommst.
>
> Ich bringe es mit, damit Max es benutzen kann.

You can find further information on [conjunctions and their usages](http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Konjunktionen/Konjunktionen.html) on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't had time to go look it up yet, are there other types of conjunctions that I should know about?

Comment: There are coordinating conjunctions (aber, denn, und, oder) and they don't change the word order or occupy a word order position. That's why it's "Die Party ist am Montag, aber ich gehe nicht", and NOT "...,aber gehe ich nicht" and also NOT "..., aber ich nicht gehe"